# Installed MinGW64, can't find make or mingw-get

Tags: mingw-w64

I installed the latest (2021-01-05) version of MinGW https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download.

It installed, but I can't find mingw-get, so I don't know how to update it. I also can't find make or bash (or rm).

How can I interact with the new version of MinGW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a good way to have a updatable MinGW environment.

For that, I would recommend using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), where within the `msys2 shell` you can get MINGW packages using the [`pacman`](https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/) package manager.

Here you have the [mingw-w64 package list](https://pastebin.com/mJHWMpFR).  (It is quite extensive - I'm using *pastebin* for that reason)

**First Edit**
After installing MSYS2 you need to add a path `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to your $PATH.

You could add it via `cmd.exe` like:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;c:\msys64\usr\bin"`

If you need to `gdb` you could use [`scoop`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/wiki/Quick-Start) which is a package manager for windows.  I'm using it regularly:

```
PS C:\Users\user> scoop search gdb
'main' bucket:
    avr-gcc (10.2.0) --> includes 'avr-gdb.exe'
    gdb (9.1-3)

PS C:\Users\user> scoop search MinGW
'extras' bucket:
    codeblocks-mingw (20.03)

'main' bucket:
    gcc (9.3.0-2) --> includes 'mingw32-make.exe'
    msys2 (2021-01-05) --> includes 'mingw'
    openssl-mingw (1.1.1i_2)

'versions' bucket:
    msys2-20200517 (2020-05-17) --> includes 'mingw'
```

Again you need to enhance your path.   I like to have the MSYS2 in the C:\ so I usually create:
`cmd /c mklink /D C:\MSYS64 C:\app_scoop\apps\msys2\current`

The instructions are for you.

For your students I would recommend creating a portable package which would include all necessary stuff.  They would need to unpack it only.

Comment: I would like to use gdb the old way as I'm handing this off to students, and the pacman commands are a bit much for them. Is this possible?

Comment: Side note: to get the above working at the command prompt, one needs to add to the PATH: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin and C:\msys64\usr\bin. I'm still working on getting g++ with MSYS2 to find libraries I needs (SDL2).

Comment: @TopologicalSort Ah, `gdb`.  Of course it is possible, but it is a lot of work on your side.  You would have to create a portable `gdb`, which can take some time (to get the path(s) right on Windows) or perphaps scoop - I will edit the answer.  Other idea would be, you could make a powershell / batch script that would prepare the environment for them.  Yes, you need to add path - I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant g++ and I wrote gdb (though I also want gdb).

Comment: @TopologicalSort `g++` will be installed with the whole MinGW toolchain.  Either you will prepare a sequence of `pacman`  commands or you will create a portable version which you will distribute.  If you do not want to make it from scratch you can check `https://portableapps.com/node/56214`.

Comment: Although I wanted the old MinGW working, I have accepted that this must be the new way. I also accepted the answer. The bounty expired. Did you get it anyway when I accepted it? If not, do you know a way I can get you those points? Help suggests it's done automatically, but I think it wasn't.

Comment: @TopologicalSort Thank you for accepting the answer.  The bounty is always time limited so when it expires (there is some overtime) the points just vanish.  No worries, I'm glad it helped.  Note: you can also upvote the answer ;).

Comment: Upvoted! Sorry I can't get you the bounty.